# ORA-00903 invalid table name in PHP Codeigniter

Tags: php, oracle, codeigniter

I got error in query Codeigniter. Here's the error

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: oci_execute(): ORA-00903: invalid table name

Filename: oci8/oci8_driver.php

Line Number: 286

Backtrace:

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\gadsb\application\helpers\odsxmlops_helper.php
Line: 1369
Function: get

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\gadsb\application\modules\occ\models\M_occ.php
Line: 181
Function: get_monthlyOther

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\gadsb\application\modules\occ\controllers\Occ.php
Line: 227
Function: dataflightmonthly

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\gadsb\index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once
```

--

```
Error Number: 903

ORA-00903: invalid table name

SELECT "M"."MONTH" AS "MONTH", "O"."ALL_OTHER" AS "ALL_OTHER" FROM SELECT TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(SCHEDULED_DEPDT_LC, 'MON-YY'), 'MM-YY') AS MONTH FROM DBODSXML4OPS.XML4OPS WHERE STATUS IN ('Scheduled') and SERVICETYPE IN ('J', 'G') and TO_CHAR(SCHEDULED_DEPDT_LC, 'yyyy-mm-dd') BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-06-07' GROUP BY TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(SCHEDULED_DEPDT_LC, 'MON-YY'), 'MM-YY') ORDER BY MONTH) M LEFT JOIN (SELECT TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(SCHEDULED_DEPDT_LC, 'MON-YY'), 'MM-YY') AS MONTH, COUNT(CASE WHEN DBODSXML4OPS.XML4OPS_DELAY.REASONCODE IN ('51','52','90','93','97','98','99') THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS ALL_OTHER FROM DBODSXML4OPS.XML4OPS JOIN DBODSXML4OPS.XML4OPS_DELAY on DBODSXML4OPS.XML4OPS.FLIGHTLEGREF = DBODSXML4OPS.XML4OPS_DELAY.FLIGHTLEGREF where STATUS IN ('Scheduled') and SERVICETYPE IN ('J','G') and TO_CHAR(SCHEDULED_DEPDT_LC, 'yyyy-mm-dd') BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-06-07' group by TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(SCHEDULED_DEPDT_LC, 'MON-YY'), 'MM-YY') order by MONTH) O ON "M"."MONTH" = "O"."MONTH" ORDER BY "M"."MONTH" DESC

Filename: C:/xampp/htdocs/gadsb/system/database/DB_driver.php

Line Number: 691
```

Is it because in `JOIN` clause I compare with `MONTH` instead of `ID`? Because in other function where I compare with `ID`, it works well.

Edit: I post the detail query below

```
SELECT M.MONTH AS MONTH, O.ALL_OTHER AS ALL_OTHER
FROM (SELECT TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(SCHEDULED_DEPDT_LC, 'MON-YY'), 'MM-YY') AS MONTH
      FROM DBODSXML4OPS.XML4OPS
      WHERE STATUS IN ('Scheduled') and SERVICETYPE IN ('J','G') and TO_CHAR(SCHEDULED_DEPDT_LC, 'yyyy-mm-dd') BETWEEN '$datefrom' AND '$dateto'
      GROUP BY TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(SCHEDULED_DEPDT_LC, 'MON-YY'), 'MM-YY')
      ORDER BY MONTH) M
LEFT JOIN (SELECT TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(SCHEDULED_DEPDT_LC, 'MON-YY'), 'MM-YY') AS MONTH, COUNT(CASE WHEN DBODSXML4OPS.XML4OPS_DELAY.REASONCODE IN ('51','52','90','93','97','98','99') THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS ALL_OTHER
           FROM DBODSXML4OPS.XML4OPS
           JOIN DBODSXML4OPS.XML4OPS_DELAY on DBODSXML4OPS.XML4OPS.FLIGHTLEGREF = DBODSXML4OPS.XML4OPS_DELAY.FLIGHTLEGREF
           where STATUS IN ('Scheduled') and SERVICETYPE IN ('J','G') and TO_CHAR(SCHEDULED_DEPDT_LC, 'yyyy-mm-dd') BETWEEN '$datefrom' AND '$dateto'
           group by TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(SCHEDULED_DEPDT_LC, 'MON-YY'), 'MM-YY')
           order by MONTH) O ON M.MONTH = O.MONTH
ORDER BY M.MONTH DESC
```

Comment: `FROM SELECT TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(SCHEDULED_DEPDT_LC, 'MON-YY'), 'MM-YY') AS MONTH` this part is throwing off your query. Remove the `FROM SELECT` and you should be good. If you're trying to get the results from another table in the first select, use parenthesis to block off the relevant part of the query

Comment: @aynber actually I already wrote parentheses after `FROM` clause. I've posted the detail query below.

Comment: In the code as posted above, `FROM SELECT` should be `FROM ( SELECT`. I'm not sure how your answer below relates to this, though.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson I already edited my question.

Comment: Your error message still shows the invalid code (missing the parentheses). Are you getting a different error now?

Comment: To clarify, I didn't realize that I forgot to put the parentheses and now it's already working. Thanks for your help!